# woocommerce_thankyou doesn't trigger consistently

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I'm trying to trigger two operations on order complete when the order only consists of products from a specific category. These products are easily recognizable by their weight of 0, which allows me to recognize these orders by their shipping method. I use this method twice, to change the recipient of the admin e-mail and to autocomplete the order.

When I test, they both work perfectly. But IRL, while the e-mail change is consistently triggered by the shipping method, many orders are not being "autocompleted". Which gives me the impression that while woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order is consistently triggered, woocommerce_thankyou isn't. I have no idea why, and it's a real problem for my client.

Any idea what might cause this?

(Full disclosure: I already brought this topic up, but because the order-selecting mechanism inside the functions was more complicated, those who answered were certain the failure of the code came from the function rather than from the woocommerce_thankyou not triggering properly. I feel with these very simple functions, there is no more doubt that the problem happens outside of the custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order function itself.)

Both functions, the one that always triggers properly, the one that doesn't:

```
/**
     * Change email recipient for admin New Order emails when the order only has products from the 'abo' category
     *
     * @param string $recipient a comma-separated string of email recipients (will turn into an array after this filter!)
     * @param \WC_Order $order the order object for which the email is sent
     * @return string $recipient the updated list of email recipients
     */

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'dada_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );

    function dada_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

        // Bail on WC settings pages since the order object isn't yet set yet
        // Not sure why this is even a thing, but shikata ga nai

        $page = $_GET['page'] = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : '';

        if ( 'wc-settings' === $page ) {
            return $recipient; 
        }

        // just in case

        if ( ! $order instanceof WC_Order ) {
            return $recipient; 
        }

            $shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method(); 

        if ( $shipping_method == 'Abonnement' ) {
            $recipient = 'newrecip@mail.fr';
        }
        else {
            $recipient = 'oldrecip@mail.fr';
        }
        return $recipient;
    }


    /**
     * Autocomplete orders with only an 'abo' product
     */

    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );

    function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method(); 

    if ( $shipping_method == 'Abonnement' ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `$order_id` is returning something?

Comment: As long as the order received page is loading the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook should fire. The only exceptions being if you have removed that from your template for some reason, _or_ you have a fatal error before you arrive at that hook. Have you turned on `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to check for errors?

Comment: Please remove those email addresses! You can replace them with fake emails.

Comment: Helga, thank you for not giving up on me. :-)

Comment: Alright, I turned debug on, should I wait for an autocomplete to fail and post the log for that day here? Also, is there no other hook that is triggered at order success that I could use to change the order status?

Comment: Hope I'm not pasting stuff I should be removing from a public conversation, but here is the most pertinent debug message I found : `[15-Oct-2017 20:39:47 UTC] PHP Notice:  payment_method_title is called the wrong way. Order properties should not be accessed directly.`

Comment: `Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/savoy/page.php'), the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, WC_Shortcodes::checkout, WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::output, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::order_received, wc_get_template, include('/themes/savoy/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php'), WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong in /home/revuedad/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4138`

Comment: However, the message appears twice only during the recorded day, and not at the time of the orders who failed to be completed automatically.

Comment: @helgatheviking Should I post a link to the full log? Also, can you confirm that calling for `$order->update_status( 'completed' );` in the email function would not work?

Comment: Could not confirm that, because I don't know. You'd have to test. Your code looks right to me, so yes: post the full log. Also consider trying my 2 step debugging process. Switch to a default theme. Does that fix it? If not, start switching off plugins one by one. Is there a specific plugin conflicting? The error you posted means that someone is accessing `$order->payment_method_title` and it needs to be switched to `$order->get_payment_method_title()`, but that shouldn't be fatal.

Comment: Sorry for the silence... Here is a link to the full log : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxiuv3blbshlxpc/debug_log.rtf?dl=0 It is filled with warnings triggered by two less-than-perfect plugins, but it doesn't seem related to the problem. I only left a few days worth of logs, but there have been a number of orders during that time, a good 2/3 of which didn't trigger the autocomplete function.

Comment: @helgatheviking : latest possibility. Could the trigger failure be caused by an exceedingly slow server response time? Google Insights shows that server response is regularly slow, and it _looks like_ there might be some correlation. Is that technically possible?

Comment: I think it is definitely worth your time to resolve some of those repeating warnings so that your log is cleaner and breaking issues are more easily traced. In a quick look it is obvious that your theme isn't updated for WooCommerce 3.0 which _could_ be related to the issue your having. [Here are some suggestions](https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/e234dd4f549df8c4cff5261be6a4fe0e). Slow server time is also a possibility. If something timed out somewhere, it's possible the page may not fully load? I'm not really sure.